# Firebase Function Error code 400 Invalid Argument

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

So I am trying to run a function on my firebase every day to clear out old events in my firestore. Right now I am just testing to get things working but can't seem to get the functions to even deploy. I have tried to figure out why it is not working for me even though I am following a tutorial to the 'T'.

Here is the function I am trying to deploy that was from a tutorial:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.scheduleCron = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('40 9 * * *')
  .onRun(context => console.log('Hello World Tester'));
```

And here is the debug log I get when I run `firebase deploy` in the root of the project. I am not sure if the issue is the node version or if there is something wrong with my firebase. I just can't seem to find what is causing the issue. I have even opened a

Debug Log: [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/C4SUBWP3)

Comment: I suggest contacting Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was able to figure out that my WSL install was using the firebase installed on my windows environment instead of linux and so the firebase tools was not updating with npm. It was at an old version that doesn't support the scheduling.